# htaccess rewrite using query string and set cookie

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write a specific rewrite rule using a query string and also a saved cookie value.

The rewrite rule for query string works (on its own):

```
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$ products.php?prodName=$1 [L]
```

which gives me:

> www.mydomain.com/product/productName

However I would also like to add into the url the saved cookie value.
The cookie value is based on directory: /, /uk, /us, /tw

So the result I am after will be:

> www.mydomain.com/uk/product/productName

Comment: How are you setting the cookie, using php or using mod-rewrite?

Comment: Thanks for looking.
By php

Comment: What is the cookie name ?

Comment: cookie name is: location